# Get Error record on bulk upsert

Tags: apex, dml, error-messages

I'm upserting a list of SObjects using Database.upsert and **I need to know which records are not inserted**.

This is an example:

```
  Account[] accts = new List<Account>{
        new Account(Name='Account1'),
        new Account(Name='Accoun2')};
    Database.upsertResult[] srList = Database.insert(accts, false);

    // Iterate through each returned result
    for (Database.upsertResult sr : srList) {
        if (sr.isSuccess()) {
            // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
            System.debug('Successfully inserted account. Account ID: ' + sr.getId());
        }
        else {
            // Operation failed, so get all errors                
            for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
                System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                System.debug('Account fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to **get the record that caused the error from**  **Database.upsertResult** ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your loop from for-each to indexed:

```
for(Integer idx = 0; idx < srList.size(); idx++) {
    if(srList[idx].isSuccess()) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

`srList[idx]` will correspond to `accts[idx]`.

This is guaranteed in the documentation:

> An array of Database.UpsertResult objects is returned with the upsert
>   database method. Each element in the UpsertResult array corresponds to
>   the sObject array passed as the sObject[] parameter in the upsert
>   Database method; that is, the first element in the UpsertResult array
>   matches the first element passed in the sObject array, the second
>   element corresponds with the second element, and so on. If only one
>   sObject is passed in, the UpsertResults array contains a single
>   element.

Comment: Can I be sure about the list order? The operations result list has always the same order than object list?

Comment: Yes, the order is guaranteed in the documentation.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the relevant information from the documentation.

Comment: goes like a charm :)